# como hago para que mi array incluya numeros y letras?

Tags: java, array

cada vez que ejecuto el código, me imprime solo la ultima letra, y necesito que imprima todos los valores que que se introduzcan en la input (incluyendo letras y números), que ajuste le puedo hacer???

```java
public class JavaApplication58 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        String Cadena = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("ingrese su contraseña");
        String[] Lista=Cadena.split("");
        String Salida="";        
         for(int i=1;i<Lista.length;i++){
             Salida=Lista[i];  
            
            
        }
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,Salida + " ","contraseña leida",JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Estás Imprimiendo fuera del ciclo for

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

String Cadena = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("ingrese su contraseña");
String[] Lista=Cadena.split("");
String Salida="";        
 for(int i=1;i<Lista.length;i++){
     Salida=Lista[i];  
    
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,Salida + " ","contraseña leida",JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
    
}
```

Prueba ahora...

Si lo que quieres es imprimir en una sola linea haz lo siguiente:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

String Cadena = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("ingrese su contraseña");
String[] Lista=Cadena.split("");
String Salida="";        
 for(int i=1;i<Lista.length;i++){
     Salida += Lista[i];  
}
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,Salida + " ","contraseña leida",JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
```

Comment: muuuchas gracias enserio

Comment: De nada, estoy para ayudar en lo que pueda. Sigue adelante!